# Vaadin session timeout and communication error

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, session-timeout

I have a couple of problems with Vaadin 7 session timeout. First is that even I tried to change heartbeatinterval to 20 seconds, Vaadin debug is still saying that it is in default value 300 s.

Another problem is that I can't get session timeout message at all but communication error message. It doesn't matter if the session is 1 min or 2 min or what ever more than heartbeatinterval.

Third problem is that there is always "invalid JSON-response from server text" in communication error message and I have no idea how to get rid of that.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>heartbeatInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>20</param-value>
</context-param>
 <context-param> 
    <param-name>closeIdleSessions</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

[image: Vaadin communication error with invalid JSON reponse]

Comment: Did you set this parameter? <session-config> <session-timeout>MINUTES</session-timeout> </session-config>

Comment: Yes. I tried everything between 1 min to 5 min just for testing purposes. Any idea for getting rid of that annoying invalid json reponse-text. I can override other texts, but not that.

Answer (score 1):

You can override these messages using your own system messages provider class. I've used this to take users to a different URL when these errors occur so I can track them in Google analytics, but you can change the caption and content of the messages instead if you like.

You will need a SystemMessagesProvider, and in your main UI class you need to add this:

```
VaadinService.getCurrent().setSystemMessagesProvider(new MyMessageProvider);
```

And your SystemMessagesProvider should look like this:

```
import com.vaadin.server.CustomizedSystemMessages;
import com.vaadin.server.SystemMessages;
import com.vaadin.server.SystemMessagesInfo;
import com.vaadin.server.SystemMessagesProvider;

public class MyMessageProvider implements SystemMessagesProvider {

    @Override
    public SystemMessages getSystemMessages(SystemMessagesInfo systemMessagesInfo) {


        CustomizedSystemMessages systemMessages = new CustomizedSystemMessages();

        systemMessages.setCommunicationErrorURL("/systemError?error=communicationError");
        systemMessages.setCommunicationErrorNotificationEnabled(false);

        systemMessages.setInternalErrorURL("/systemError?error=internalError");
        systemMessages.setInternalErrorNotificationEnabled(false);

        systemMessages.setSessionExpiredURL("/systemError?sessionTimeout");
        systemMessages.setSessionExpiredNotificationEnabled(false);

        return systemMessages;
    }
```

Comment: In another project I've done, I set the communication error URL to be the URI of my application, then when a communication error occurs it simply reloads the application. The user won't see anything but it will be a new VaadinSession, it worked nicely for me as my application was stateless.

Comment: i have done that already. The problem is that I never got session expired text but communication error. And i decided to get rid of that annoying json text with css, because I still have no idea why it is there and it is impossible to override.